# How to capture WCF Data Service Request/ Response messages

Tags: odata, wcf-data-services

I have built a WCF Data Service with an updatable data context. I want to capture the Request and Response messages when I consume this service using my client. How do I go about it?
Appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fiddler from http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Thanks @Monica. Earlier I was trying with the VS web server and Fiddler was not capturing any traffic. This time I tried hosting my service in IIS and it worked! I could see the requests/ responses in Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

It's very very difficult to get Fiddler to work with the built-in Web server in VS (between localhost and the non-standard port). Your time is better spent getting the data service to run in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to dump the messages using a [WCF Message Inspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx).